# How can I combine two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqOtG.png)

Hello, I am trying to take this result by using 311-service-requests.csv.
There are Created Date and Closed Date columns. I took difference of these columns to find closing_time_hours. Also I found Complaint Type counts.

Here my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dao5V.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

complaints = pd.read_csv("311-service-requests.csv", sep = ",")
complaint_counts = complaints['Complaint Type'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
print(complaint_counts)

start_time = pd.to_datetime(complaints['Created Date'].astype(str))
end_time = pd.to_datetime(complaints['Closed Date'].astype(str))

complaints['diff_seconds'] = end_time - start_time
complaints['diff_seconds'] = complaints['diff_seconds']/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
diff_time= complaints.groupby("Complaint Type")["diff_seconds"].mean()

print(pd.concat([complaint_counts, diff_time], axis=1).head(10))
```

Here my result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsJjo.png)

Street Light Condition = -18.893000. Look, the time diff here is a negative value. Why might this be due? End time can't not be smaller than start time. So result must be positive. I guess it is because of missing values at dataframe.

Comment: What problem with your outputs? I don't see any NaN values on your screenshot. Also it looks like you only save `.head(10)` of your `complaint_counts`. Try to move this `.head(10)` to the `print(complaint_counts.head(10))`, maybe this would help you

Comment: At the top of the counts number column name is "Complaint Type". I guess result is true but columns names design is false. Can I design names for better 
appearance.

Comment: "NaN" is in the data. I thought that mean values ​​might be calculated incorrectly because some values ​​are missing. However, I think there is no problem in that regard as you told.

Comment: Street Light Condition = -18.893000. Look, the time diff here is a negative value. Why might this be due?

Comment: You can use `.rename` function to change series name: `complaints['Complaint Type'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).rename('Complaint Type Counts')`. Yo answer why you have negative value, you need to show `complaints` dataframe

Comment: Okey it's better now. Thank you. I will try to fix negative value. End time can't not be smaller than start time. So result must be positive. I guess it is because of missing values at dataframe.